# Why doesn't change in .spec.template.metadata.labels for ReplicaSet impact pods

Tags: kubernetes

I have a `ReplicaSet` defined in a yaml file which was used to create 2 pods (replicas). It is my understanding that changes in the `spec` section of `ReplicaSet` will be interpreted as changes in the desired state that will eventually get applied to the real world. For example, PATCHing the number of replicas with:

```
curl --request PATCH \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/strategic-merge-patch+json' \
     --data '{"spec":{"replicas":3}}' \
     http://localhost:8080/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/replicasets/hello-v2
```

causes the number of pods to change. However, if I patch the labels to add a label:

```
 curl --request PATCH \
      --header 'Content-Type: application/strategic-merge-patch+json' \
      --data '{"spec": {"template": {"metadata":{"labels":{"active":"true"}}}}}' \
      http://localhost:8080/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/replicasets/hello-v2
```

I don't see this change take place on existing pods. New pods (created, for example by scaling the ReplicaSet *do* contain the new label.

When does a change to a `spec` impact the current state and when does it not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A change to the Template will only show up when that Template is used to stamp out new replicas. A change outside of the Template (replicas/selector) will be enacted immediately. If you want to gracefully change the PodSpec or labels of already existing Pods, you should take a look at the Rolling Update functionality of [Deployments](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/).